# WDK : security consideration - can i prevent other applications to use a driver?

Tags: windows, winapi, wdk

im doing a usb hook driver that will expose a set of functions that i will use from my application.

Problem is that these functions that i expose would basically enable someone else to use the same to create ex keyboard sniffer applications, so i have abit of a security concern here installing this on machines.

Is there any way you can set a relationsship so only my application are able to access this driver ?

Comment: Only *your* application, no.  Only applications with administrative privilege, yes, and in fact I think that's the default in most cases.  If the application must be usable by non-administrative users, consider writing a system service that will talk to the driver on the users behalf.

Comment: What does "expose a set of functions that i will use from my application" mean? User-mode code (your application) can't call kernel-mode functions. Perhaps you meant something a little different.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: If the application is a UWP app it gets a unique SID, somewhat similar to Vista Service SIDs, and you can use that to limit access to a specific (UWP) app.

Comment: @conio, it looks like that's implemented using AppContainers, and I *think* that means that to be granted access to a resource the permissions need to grant access to *both* both the standard part of the token *and* the AppContainer SID.  Otherwise a UWP app being run by one user wouldn't be properly isolated from the data stored by the same UWP app in another user's account.  **However,** the documentation doesn't make this clear, so I would have to try it out to be sure.  Perhaps when I get back to the office, later this week.

Comment: ... on the other hand, I imagine that a driver can examine the user's token directly, and enforce any rules it wants, including "only requests with this particular AppContainer SID are allowed" even if a normal Windows ACL can't do that.  MT, what versions of Windows do you need to support?